# Can I create a ServiceBehavior that will replace the OperationBehaviors I already apply to every Operation in my Service?

Tags: wcf, servicebehavior

I know all the operations in this service will require the same OperationBehavior.. could I implement a ServiceBehavior that will perform the same functionality before the operation is run?

I currently have:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [AuthTokenValidation]
    [OperationContract]
    string DoThis(string authtoken);
}
```

I want to replace it with:

```
[AuthTokenValidation]
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string DoThis(string authtoken);
}
```

Inside my AuthTokenValidation attribute, I have the following code in the ApplyDispatchBehavior method:

```
public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
{
    AuthTokenInspector inspector;

    inspector = new AuthTokenInspector(AuthTokenIndex);
    dispatchOperation.ParameterInspectors.Add(inspector);
}
```

I checked the ApplyDispatchBehavior method in IServiceBehavior, but I couldnt figure out how to access the DisppatchOperation that was currently being called.

```
public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
{
    //Can I reach the OperationDispatch from in here??
}
```

Is this the proper way to use ServiceBehavior or should I just be satisfied with OperationBehaviors to implement this functionality?

Comment: If all operations need to implement the same behavior why would you care which operation is being invoked in the `ApplyDispatchBehavior` method?

Comment: In the ApplyDispatchBehavior I add an IParameterInspector to dispatchOperation.ParameterInspectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried is but I'd have thought you could get to your DispatchOperation as follows:

- serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers (get a collection of ChannelDispatchers)
- ChannelDispatcher.Endpoints (get the Endpoints for a ChannelDispatcher)
- Endpoint.DispatchRuntime.Operations (get the Operations for an Endpoint)

Comment: damn, you're right. that almost worked. I didnt see the Endpoints property earlier because I used a foreach loop with a var instance instead of casting it into a ChannelDispatcher (the var doesnt show the Endpoints property).  But in the end, I was able to add the inspector to the ParameterInspectors, but for some reason the inspector never gets called!

Comment: ok the reason it didnt work for me initially, was because I was adding my IServiceBehavior attribute to the service contract and not the service implementation class... thanks a lot for the answer joe!